# Resources folder not working when exported

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, resources, export

I've got this strange problem with Java/Eclipse. I use this to load BufferedImages (and a similar one to load Fonts):

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ResourceLoader.class.getClassLoader();
ImageIO.read(new File(classLoader.getResource(path).getFile()));
```

This code is in a class called ResourceLoader. It is an utility class that I made and use to load BufferedImages and Fonts. Everything works in Eclipse, but when exported to executable JAR, it throws a nullPointerException when trying to load the resources. I looked into the JAR and the resources are packed in there.

The path is in the following format: `"/img/paper.png"`

Here is the hierarchy of my project:

[image: My project hierarchy]

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of jars are not files and folders, so you can not access their internals as if they were. The classloader can give you a direct `InputStream` for the resource. `ImageIO` can take an `InputStream`. Use them together.